# How to Bind font to my DataGridHeader from my Helper class

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, binding

How to Bind font to my DataGridHeader from my Helper class, which is called Globals and it is public static, like this:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static int DataGridfontSizeHeader { get; set; }
    public static int DataGridfontSizeContent { get; set; }
}
```

In this class I am holding values of FontSize.

Now I would like to apply values from this class to my DataGrid column header and DataGrid content (fontsize of data presented in rows and columns)

I tried something like this for header :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="Yellow" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding MyProject.Helpers.Globals.DataGridfontSizeHeader }"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,17,0"/>
    <!--Margin to shift the entire header to the right 17 units to fill the void-->
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-17,0"/>
</Style>
```

But unfortunatelly it is not working,

so my question is how to apply fonts from this Global class to my DataGrid Content and to DataGrid Header columns?

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the properties to `double` and specify a valid font size as the default value:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static double DataGridfontSizeHeader { get; set; } = 10;
    public static double DataGridfontSizeContent { get; set; } = 10;
}
```

Then you can set the value of the property in the `Style` like this:

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Static local:Globals.DataGridfontSizeHeader}"/>
```

"local" is a namespace mapping to the CLR namespace where your class is defined:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window23"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    ...
```

**Edit:**

> yes, this ability to have auto property initializers is included since C# 6.0 and unfortunately I'm using C# 5.0 and as you can see my class is static so I can't define it in constructor because static classes can't have a contructor, hmmmmm

Just define a `static` constructor:

```
public static class Globals
{
    static Globals()
    {
        DataGridfontSizeHeader = 10;
        DataGridfontSizeContent = 10;
    }

    public static double DataGridfontSizeHeader { get; set; }
    public static double DataGridfontSizeContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: after I added this I am getting 0 is not valid for the System.Window.Document.TextElement FontSize error in blend studio.. what that might be, all types are double as you said .. ?

Comment: You need to set the property to a valid value as I stated in my answer. 0 is not a valid value. You cannot set the FontSize to 0. In my sample code I have set the default value of both properties to 10.

Comment: yes, this ability to have auto property initializers is included since C# 6.0 and unfortunately I'm using C# 5.0 and as you can see my class is static so I can't define it in constructor because static classes can't have a contructor, hmmmmm

Comment: Just define a static constructor. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to bind an `int` property of your class to a `double` `FontSize` property (it will throw an exception).

Secondly, while you can sort of "bind" to static properties (see [**@mm8**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952873/891715) answer) it is a one time only sort of binding, since `INotifyPropertyChanged` makes sense only for instances. So the changes you'll make to your static properties on runtime wont be reflected.

The solution here would be to use a singleton pattern instead.